# Possible to generate full Android app "sitetree"?

Tags: android, auto-generate

I want to visualise the full structure of our Android app, and I'm hoping there's a way to generate that structure including the app views. It's the equivalent of a sitetree for websites. Does anybody know of any methods to do that?